# Remove Backup Job

Tags: sql-server, backup, database-backups

I am trying to remove backup jobs from MS SQL Server Studio 2012.

There are many links such as [this one](http://www.serverintellect.com/support/sqlserver/database-backup-ssmse/) that explain how to create backup jobs, but none that say how to remove them.

Thank you.

When I go to SQL Server Agent > Jobs > Right-click on a Job > Click Delete

I get error

[image]

Comment: Did you try deleting the SQL Server Agent Job?

Comment: @WEI_DBA I updated question

Comment: Ok. Makes more sense now. So you can either go into the Maintenance Plans and delete the plan, then delete the agent job or just disable the agent job, if you can't delete the maintenance plan.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I ended up disabling the jobs (error when I try deleting something, even though job was created with same `sa` account)